# Kinesis Read Failing for some records

Tags: amazon-kinesis

The metric `GetRecord.success` shows a value zero for some period. Does that mean some records are not read from Kinesis? `ReadProvisionedThroughputExceeded` value is zero though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happens because GetRecords can return an empty Record element even when there is data in the kinesis stream.

GetRecords is a non-blocking operation, and is intended to be used in a "pull" model, e.g. the consuming application  calls GetRecords inside a loop (this is not required in KCL that does the job for you). I've used the expression "pull", but actually records are never removed by the consumer. Call getRecords has only the effect of increasing the consumer's offset.

Make GetRecords non-blocking was an architectural choice to avoid unbounded seek time (latency) when retrieving records.

Actually, call GetRecors can return an empty Record element even when there is data in the stream. This situation occurs in two cases:
-there is no more data currently in the shard, or
-there is no data near the part of the shard pointed to by the ShardIterator.

For more information, you can check this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/troubleshooting-consumers.html